# How do I get my app in a docker instance to talk to my database in another docker instance inside the same network?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Ok I give up! I spent far too much time on this:

So I want my app inside a docker container to talk to my postgres which is inside another container.

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  foodbudget-db:
    container_name: foodbudget-db
    image: postgres:12.4
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      POSTGRES_DB: foodbudget
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
  web:
    image: node:14.10.1
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - foodbudget-db
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.10.1

WORKDIR /src/app

ADD https://github.com/palfrey/wait-for-db/releases/download/v1.0.0/wait-for-db-linux-x86 /src/app/wait-for-db
RUN chmod +x /src/app/wait-for-db
RUN ./wait-for-db -m postgres -c postgresql://user:pass@foodbudget-db:5433 -t 1000000

EXPOSE 8080
```

But I keep getting this error when I build the Dockerfile, even though the database is up and running when I run `docker ps`. I tried connecting to the postgres database in my host machine, and it connected successfully...
`Temporary error (pausing for 3 seconds): PostgresError { error: Error(Io(Custom { kind: Other, error: "failed to lookup address information: Name does not resolve" })) }`

Have anyone created an app and talk to a db in another docker instance be4?

Answer (score 0):

This line is the issue:

```
RUN ./wait-for-db -m postgres -c postgresql://user:pass@foodbudget-db:5433 -t 1000000
```

You must use the internal port of the docker container (5432) instead of the exposed one within a network:

```
RUN ./wait-for-db -m postgres -c postgresql://user:pass@foodbudget-db:5432 -t 1000000
```